# Jquery ui draggable and droppable: Snap an element to center of a grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grid, jquery-ui-draggable

I wanted to know how it's possible to snap an element to the center of the grid. In the fiddle you can see that the element snaps to the edges, not to the center. (How) is it possible to do a snap to the middle?

http://jsfiddle.net/CbESD/

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable">drag</div>
<div id="droppable">drop</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
    snap: '#droppable',
    snapMode: 'inner'
});

$('#droppable').droppable({});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a dead simple way of doing this, so instead I created a hidden helper div for the draggable to snap to. It gets positioned within the droppable div and the snap is set to that, instead of the droppable itself. This should pretty much perfectly simulate the center snap.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CbESD/1/)**

**jQuery**

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
    snap: '#helper',
    snapMode: 'inner'
});
$('#droppable').droppable({});
$('#draggable').clone().html('').prop('id', 'helper').appendTo('#droppable').removeClass('ui-draggable')
```

**CSS**

```
#draggable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    z-index:1;
}
#droppable {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 2px solid;
    background: gray;
    position:relative;
}
#helper {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    position: absolute !important;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I already thought about that solution but thought that there might be simpler ones!

Comment: Cowardly downvoter care to share some constructive criticism?

Comment: @CRAIG Finally! ;)